# How to pass returned value from javascript async function to python variable

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

```
var = driver.execute_script("setTimeout(function(){ return [1,2,3]; }, 1000);")
```

Using `Selenium`'s function `execute_script`, I'm trying to get data out of a website using `javascript` and pass it to a `python` variable `var`, the problem is that the `javascript` code that collects the data takes around 1 second to complete collecting the data (because of some animations), so when the line of code above is executed, the right value at that time is `None` (because the `javascript` code didn't return anything), but, 1 second later the right value will be changed to the data needed, still `var` will be `None` because that's the value assigned to it.
Note that this line of code works well, but that's not exactly what needed.

```
var = driver.execute_script("return [1,2,3];")
```

I have solutions to the problem but I'm looking for better ones:

1. let the javascript code download the data to a file, and after `time.sleep` for the python code, let var get the data from that file
2. similar to 1, let the javascript code push the data to somewhere in the website, and after `time.sleep` for the python code, let var get the data from the website.
3. just use raw `Selenium` code, which I don't prefer because I don't know other than the basics of `Selenium`

Comment: I think if you use raw Selenium Explicit waits, you would be able to solve this issue. 3rd point from your question

Comment: You can do it using async / await.

Comment: @Invizi can you explain please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a python library asyncio that lets you use async await in python.

```py
import asyncio
import request

async def do_task():
    response = await request("https://example.com")
    return response.text
```

as you can see above, we can use await to tell python to wait for the value before continuing.

Comment: Still doesn't work, the code I tried is here:
https://codeshare.io/K8gZOo

Comment: By the looks of the selenium docs, you want to swap .execute_script with .execute_async_script